# Open multiple work items in TFS 2013 Team Web Access

Tags: tfs, tfs-web-access

In TFS 2010 Team Web Access I could open multiple work items and compare them. In TFS 2013 Team Web Access this doesn't appear to be supported. Each time you open a work item it displays in a modal window which makes it impossible to open another work item.

What's the best way to open multiple work items for comparison? Clearly the new TWA was not intended to be used this way.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way is to solve this with the Browser. You can have multiple windows and just copy the URL to a new window. That way you can also use multi-monitor as well.